# How to read a password protected .csv file from zip folder into R?

Tags: r, encryption, zip

I need to read an encrypted .csv file from a zipped folder (.zip) into R.

My current code used to extract the file when it is decrypted and unzipped looks like this:

```
test_2017= as.data.table(read.csv("Raw Data/DATASET1_PART1.csv"))
```

The problem with this is that due to the size of the decompressd file, I am losing rows when I simply move it from the zip folder onto the regular drive. Therefore I need to read it directly from the zip folder.

Can anyone help?

Comment: “I am losing rows when I simply move it from the zip folder onto the regular drive” — This should **never** happen, and is almost certainly unrelated to being decompressed on disk. Out of interest, how big is the file?

Comment: Hi Konrad, my apologies, somehow I did not see your reply!! It seems the issue may be related to versions of excel perhaps? Either way, being able to extract directly from a zip file into R would bypass this step and make for easier reading of files for me in general. Is this possible using R?

Comment: The file is over 195,000 KB in size.